# object for key based on int number

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
int number = 3;

NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"Apple",[NSNumber numberWithInt:0],
                               @"Peach",[NSNumber numberWithInt:1],
                               @"Lemon",[NSNumber numberWithInt:2],
                               @"Pineapple",[NSNumber numberWithInt:3],
                               ........................,
                               nil];

NSString *numberToKey = [dict objectForKey:number];
```

How insert in the string the value of the dict based on int number?

Answer (score 3):

The same way you put the values into the dictionary:

```
NSString *numberToKey = [dict objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:number]];
```

Comment: Upvote.  You can't pass in an int where it's expecting a pointer type object, since it will think the int is the pointer itself; using [NSNumber] is the way to go.